# Sass flex order does nothing on generated elements

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, sass, flexbox

I have a couple of SVG that get rendered like this

```
export const MenuHeaderTab = (props: RenderableProps<Props>) => 
{
    const css = props.isActive ? "menu-tab menu-tab-selected" : "menu-tab";

    return (
        <div onClick={() => props.onClick()} className={css}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

the problem i have is that in desktop mode it works fine cause they render in the order that i want them to. the problem is that in mobile portrait mode i want one of the rendered SVG to be first in the order (row). So i thought i use row and just set the className on the SVG

so here is the sass/css

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait)
{
    .menu-tab {
        width: 10%;
        height: 20%;
        margin-left: 4vw;
    }
    .menu-close-button {
        order: -1;
    }
    .menu-leaderboard-button {
        order: 2;
    }
    .menu-prize-button {
        order: 3;
    }
    .menu-rules-button {
        order: 4;
    }
```

so i even provided order to all the SVG and -1 to the one that should be first, but they all stay in the exact same order still. Anyone have any clue why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Order attribute only works if the father element use `display: flex`*

Assuming the `.menu-tab` is the father's div of this elements `.menu-close-button, .menu-leaderboard-button, .menu-prize-button, .menu-rules-button`, you just need to set a `display: flex` to the `.menu-tab`

Bellow follow an example of the code:
*Look athe the close button, its the last element but how its set -1 as order, it become the first element*

```css
.menu-tab {
 width: 10%;
 height: 20%;
 margin-left: 4vw;
 display: flex;
}
.menu-tab a{
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu-close-button {
 order: -1;
}
.menu-leaderboard-button {
 order: 2;
}
.menu-prize-button {
 order: 3;
}
.menu-rules-button {
 order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-tab">
  <a href="#" class="menu-leaderboard-button">leaderboard</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-prize-button">Prize</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-rules-button">Rules</a>
  <a href="" class="menu-close-button">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I will mark this as the right answer i need to change it up a level in my hierarchy but thanks i didn't know that the direct parent must have flex. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, its nice that helped you !!